# How to get table records for duplicate values?

Tags: sql, db2

I have TABLE1 with 3 columns(ssn, first name, last name) in it. I got list of duplicate SSNs in the table by using this query:

```
SELECT SSN, COUNT(SSN) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY SSN HAVING COUNT(SSN) > 1
```

Now I want to get all records in the table for duplicate SSNs that I got from query above. How to do that? I am using DB2. Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I know that SSN should be unique but strangely my table has duplicate ssn's with different names.

Comment: SSNs can be associated with multiple names as long as the names are aliases for a unique individual. E.g., I have two names registered with the SSA.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use it in an `IN` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE SSN IN (SELECT SSN FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY SSN HAVING COUNT(SSN) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by ssn) as cnt
      from table1
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If can use a where in with the subselect

```
 select * from TABLE1 
 where  ssn in (
   SELECT SSN FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY SSN HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This works by assigning a rownumber for each duplicate and selecting only that got more a rownumber lager than one.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE SSN IN (
    select ssn from (
       select ssn, row_number() over (partition by ssn) as rang from table1
                    ) tmp 
    where rang>1 
 )
```